# ;Jquery: animate page down 100px from current screen position

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I need to animate a scroll from the current screen position, down a set number of pixels.

```
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).position().top += 100
    });
```

or?

```
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=100px'
    });
```

Comment: then use that point as a selector from where you want to down the window position not html,body

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just change:

```
scrollTop: $('body').position().top += 100
```

To this:

```
scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fpxuC/

Comment: i am not able to replicate this example, could you pleas provide an example in which i could start the animation with a click event

Answer (score 2):

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).position().top += 100
    })

$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=100px'
    })

scrollTop: $('body').position().top += 100

scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery.ScrollTo plugin. You can do something like: `$(...).scrollTo( '+=100px', 800 );`

Check out the sample for everything this plugin can do: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Jquery has it's own scrollTop, scrollto isn't needed