# Scroll Top not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon click of my button I'm trying to set the page to scroll to 1000px down.

I've tried:

```
 $(window).scrollTop(1000);
```

And

```
 $(document).scrollTop(1000);
```

And

```
 $('body').scrollTop(1000);
```

Jquery is in my page so that is not the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: animate page down 100px from current screen position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883105/jquery-animate-page-down-100px-from-current-screen-position)

Comment: Not a dup as I dont wish to animate.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: scroll To does not work either.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('body,html').scrollTop(1000);
```

I guess it's because you're testing in Firefox, which gets the scrollTop from the html element and not the body's.